# Are .htaccess files ignored by default in an Apache setup on Ubuntu 12.04 / 14.04 LTS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

When setting up the most minimal Apache installation possible (which seems to be standard in most tutorials these days) like this...

(on a naked Ubuntu 12.04 / 14.04 LTS)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

...then `.htaccess` files (even if they just have a simple `deny from all` inside) are completely ignored (because the vhost default config has an AllowOverride None inside 12.04 respectivly nothing inside 14.04).

**Question**

Is this definitly Apache2's standard on Ubuntu 12.04 / 14.04 LTS's or am I just using weird server providers ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, this is the default configuration of Apache in 14.04 LTS.

My `/etc/apache2.conf` had this by default:

```
...
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

and the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` had this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to...{removed lengthy text}
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels..{removed lengthy text}
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at...{removed lengthy text}
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```